How to get access to the keys of a hash map as an iterator while also having a mutable reference to the hash map in Rust?
I have this, which works:
   let clients: &mut HashMap<usize, _some_none_clonable_type> = &mut self.clients;
   let keys = {
      let mut keys = Vec::<usize>::new();
      for key in clients.keys(){
         keys.push(*key);
      }
      keys
   };
   if let Some(client) = clients.get_mut(&id) {
      println!("INFO: The !users macro was sent from user: {id}.");
      client.write_all(format!("User ID's:\n").as_bytes())?;
      for user_id in keys {
         client.write_all(format!("{user_id}\n").as_bytes())?;
      }
   }

But what I actually want is this:
   // first mutable borrow of hashmap
   if let Some(client) = self.clients.get_mut(&id) {
      println!("INFO: The !users macro was sent from user: {id}.");
      client.write_all(format!("User ID's:\n").as_bytes())?;
      // immutable borrow of the same map in the same scope:
      for user_id in self.clients.keys() {
         client.write_all(format!("{user_id}\n").as_bytes())?;
      }
   }

Correct me if I'm wrong but since we don't mutate the keys and we never remove anything, this code should be valid, just not well typed. Of course the compiler complains. Is there a way to circumvent the type checker by using indirections or unsafe? I realize that it's not necessary because I could just check if the entry exists in the hash map and only then borrow, but I'm actually more interested in this type of scenario in general.

The only way to get a unique reference to a value in the map is to start with a unique reference to the map itself; this then precludes other (aliasing) references to the map's keys. What you can do it to put the values (client) into a RefCell, which allows you to mutably borrow the specific value from a shared references to the map, which in turn does not preclude having aliasing references to the keys. This comes with a small runtime cost, yet fundamentally it guarantees that the keys do not alias with the values, for which you claim unique access.

"Correct me if I'm wrong but since we don't mutate the keys and we never remove anything, this code should be valid, just not well typed." forbidding concurrent unique and shared references is at the core of the language semantics, even with improvements to the borrow checker your program is illegal period end of the story, it goes against either the the core tenet of the language, or the second most important rule.

Incidentally your copy of the keys is unnecessarily complicated, it could just be clients.keys().copied().collect::<Vec<_>>();.

Changing the hashmap to HashMap<usize, RefCell<_some_non_clone_type>> did work. I borrow the map immutably and then access the reference mutably which works, since the reference itself is borrowed immutably. Indirections are op! One commenter @Masklinn said that the original code cannot be correct even disregarding the type system, I fail to see why. I find these things quite challenging to understand, so if someone can explain in more detail, would love to read it.

@PhthaloJohnson, don't get hung up on technical terms like "just not well typed", "the type system" - those terms only get people to argue about such terms. The gist of your problem is that - as I said earlier - the only way to get a unique reference (otherwise known as mutable reference) to a value in the map is to start with a unique reference to the map itself. But this then means that there can't be any other references to anything in the map, including the keys. Consider the case where a key referred to a value. Don't cheat on "Yeah, but in my case, ..." - it doesn't work
